# ACRCloud music recognition in Android service

Tags: android, kotlin, acrcloud

I followed the demo app in the ACRCloud Android sdk. All the code for music recognition was in the activity.

I did the same but in a service. So can we initialize the ACRCloudClient in the service?(ACRCloudClient extends from Activity).

How can we then do it in the service if we can't.

I have the implementation code in the service in another question. Here is the link [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705028/acrcloud-integration-to-android-app/49707652?noredirect=1#comment86429097_49707652)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the implementation of the ACRCloudClient and its extends android Activity. Also ACRCloudClient uses shared preferences(that's why I am getting a null pointer exception).

Since keeping a reference to an activity in a service is not a good Idea its best to Implement the above code in the activity. All the implementation of recognizing is being done in a separate thread anyway in the ACRCloudClient class so there is no point of creating another service for that.

I answered the same in another question as well [link to related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705028/acrcloud-integration-to-android-app/49707652?noredirect=1#comment86429097_49707652)

Answer (score 0):

SDK can work in a service, but because SDK needs recording, it may be interrupted during execution in the background.Can your implementation code work now? 
You can set "this.mConfig.context = null", and ignore that null exception.